# Can numbers smaller than infinitesimals exist?

Tags: real-analysis, infinity, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

I have a good idea of infinitesimals to some extent.( A bit of non standard analysis)
I am reading the book of keisler on non standard analysis and calculus.
I am okay with them all but, if "a" is an hyperreal number then 2a,3a.... Are also infinitesimals right?
So can I do,0.5a,0.00009a..... if yes then can much smaller numbers than infinitesimals exist?

Comment: you would need to create an alternative model (I dont know if possible) that define numbers smaller than infinitesimals

Comment: You can read about the surreal numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number

Comment: Further to @EthanBolker's comment, the surreal numbers are [one of several options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal#Number_systems_that_include_infinitesimals).

Comment: Aren't $0.5a,0.00009a, \dots$ also infinitesimals?

Comment: You can consider nilpotents as smaller type of infinitesimals than non-nilpotent infinitesimals.

Answer (score 3):

If you define $x$ as positive infinitesimal if $x>0$ while $x<y$ for all positive reals, negative infinitesimal if $-x$ is positive infinitesimal, and infinitesimal as either, by definition anything smaller than an infinitesimal is another infinitesimal or $0$, and hence no further concept is needed.

But infinitesimals form a hierarchy if they aren't nilpotent. For example, a positive infinitesimal $\varepsilon$ satisfies $\varepsilon>\varepsilon^2>\varepsilon^3>\cdots>0$, unless $\epsilon^n=0$ for sufficiently large $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: I understood the fact that there exists number systems like surreal numbers,levi-cevita... But I think this not answers my question. Any other answers please.

Comment: @Rahul If this doesn't answer your question, your question is unclear. Please update it to clarify what else you're looking for.

Comment: @Rahul, $\varepsilon^2$ is an infinitesimal that is much smaller than the infinitesimal $\varepsilon$. But they're both infiniesimals, as J.G. points out.

Comment: But Mark S. How long can I go?

Comment: I mean varepsilon^2 is also an infinitesimal then how long can I do this process. If I do it infinitely many times,what number I reach?

Comment: @Rahul Do you mean "what is the infimum?" or "what is the infimum, which I assume is literally reached, even though that's not how infima work even with $\{r^n|n\in\Bbb N\}$ for real $r\in(0,\,1)$?"?

Comment: Clearly I want to know ,.                                                         {dx,dx/2,dx/3.......dx/n} What does this sequence goes to as n goes to infinity. Is it an infinitesimal or number smaller than it?

Comment: @Rahul If $\varepsilon$ is infinitesimal with $\varepsilon^2>0$, $\varepsilon/n>c\varepsilon^2$ for all $n\in\Bbb N,\,c\in(0,\,\infty)$, so $\{\varepsilon/n|n\in\Bbb N\}$ doesn't have a greatest lower bound, i.e. infimum.

Comment: So J.G., do you mean that {x/n|n is natural number} for x is an infinitesimal doesn't converge?

Comment: @Rahul Even $\{1/n|n\in\Bbb N\}$ won't have an infimum ("converge" is a sequence property) once infinitesimals are introduced. But "do all sets of infinitesimals have an infimum?" is a very different question from the one you started with.